# Read numbers from control file and Extract matching line numbers from the data file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have a control file  - cntl.txt

```
2
3
5
```

Data file - data.txt

```
red
blue
yellow
green
violet
orange
```

I need to reading the lines matching from control file, here the output expected is:

```
blue
yellow 
violet
```

Answer (score 5):

Example of a very inefficient solution:

```
for i in $(<control.txt); do awk -v c=$i 'NR~c{ print $0 }' data.txt; done;
```

I report also a good solution I learned tonight:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ z[$0]++;next }; FNR in z' control.txt data.txt
```

Comment: What @don_crissti said is true.  Also see [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)

Comment: @don_crissti You're right. I knew it's very inefficient, but unfortunately it's the best that I thought. I still have a lot to learn, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your `awk` solution is certainly worth an upvote imho (especially since the OP tagged `awk`)

Comment: note that `z[$0]` alone will do... no need of `++`...

Answer (score 4):

Using only [POSIX specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) features of Sed:

```
sed -n -e "$(sed '/./s/$/p/' cntl.txt)" data.txt
```

Of course if your `cntl.txt` file has lines besides numbers, you may get an error.  But if it has empty lines these will be handled correctly (i.e. they will not affect the output).

Comment: This does not work if you have 10+ lines, as join expects a lexicographically sorted data.

Comment: @zeppelin, you are quite correct.  I've upvoted your answer and have now removed the incorrect portion of this answer.

Comment: I've upvoted your updated answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
join <(nl data.txt|sort -k1b,1) <(cat cntl.txt|sort -k1b,1) | sort -nk1,1 | cut -d' ' -f2-
```

nl - will enumerate lines for you

```
 1  red
 2  blue
 3  yellow
 4  green
 5  violet
 6  orange
```

| sort -k1b,1 - will sort them by the line number (first field), lexicographically

cat cntl.txt| sort -k1b,1 - will sort the control file in the same order

```
2
3
5
```

join <() <() - will join the sorted (and numbered) "data" with the sorted "control", on the first field (i.e. line number)

```
2 blue
3 yellow
5 violet
```

|sort -nk1,1 - will re-sort the results numerically (to put the lines back in order)

| cut -d' ' -f2- - will drop the line number field

```
blue
yellow
violet
```

Comment: > That seems silly
That is not silly, as join operates on the lexicographically and not numerically sorted data.

Comment: > Also, <(...) is a Bash-ism, not specified by POSIX
Yep, this is probably not canonicaly POSIX, but it is not a bash-only extension either, at least _ksh_ and _zsh_ do support this too.

Answer (score 2):

With `sed` only:

```
sed -n "$(sed -e 's/$/p;/' < cntl.txt)" data.txt
```

Comment: Good, but no reason to use `tr`.  Newlines are a perfectly acceptable command separator for Sed.  (Also, `$(...)` is the preferred syntax for command substitution.)

Answer (score -1):

Another possible solution:

```
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a colors < 'data.txt'; unset IFS;

for i in $(<cntl.txt); do
        echo ${colors[i-1]} 
done
```

IFS line sets up internal file separator as newline and inserts each line from data.txt into array. After that you loop through lines in cntl.txt and print array elements with given index from it (minus 1 because you start your data.txt from 1, not from 0, otherwise it would be unnecessary).

Comment: See [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/135943)