# How to delete all occurrences of a list of words from a text file?

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep, text

I have a file containing a list of words. I want to remove all occurrences of all the words in this file from a big text file.

Example:

File 1

```
queen
king
```

Text file sample

```
Both the king and queen are monarchs. Will the queen live? Queen, it is!
```

This is what I have tried:

```
sed -i 's/queen/ /g' page.txt
sed -i 's/Queen/ /g' page.txt
```

Output

```
Both the and are monarchs. Will the live? , it is!
```

The list of words I have is big (over 50000 words). How can I do this without having to specify the pattern in the command line?

Comment: So you need this to be i) case insensitive and ii) ignore punctuation (`queen,` matches `queen`)? How about substrings? Should `king` match `hiking`? Or `high-king`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Where did you get stuck?  See http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/112023/135943 if you're just starting out.  (Show *some* effort and you're more likely to get help; there is a *wealth* of information on this site already, very easily searchable.)

Comment: @terdon Just full string matches. punctuation is ignored.

Comment: @Wildcard I have been able to use sed to remove all occurrences of a single word specified in the command line. I am not sure how to do that if there are multiple words, to be read from a file.

Comment: Excellent. Please [edit] your question and add the command you've used and how it fails in this case.

Comment: As of _How can I do this without having to specify the pattern in the command line?_ `sed` allows to submit expressions from a file via its option `-f`. You could even write `sed` "programs" by prepending `#!/usr/bin/sed -f` to such a file and giving it execute permissions. However, with 50000 expressions I agree that `sed` seems to be an inappropriate choice.

Answer (score 7):

For your actual use case I recommend [terdon's answer using Perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/322316/135943).

However, the simple version, without handling words that are substrings of other words (e.g. removing "king" from "hiking"), is to [use one Sed command to generate the command run by a different Sed instance](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/320668/135943) on your actual file.

In this case, with `wordfile` containing "king" and "queen" and `textfile` containing your text:

```
sed -e "$(sed 's:.*:s/&//ig:' wordfile)" textfile
```

Note that the "`i`gnore case" flag is a GNU extension, not standard.

Comment: The `sed` solution to this problem is rarely found on the web. — Feels like finding gold dust…

Answer (score 4):

The simple but inefficient way is to process the file multiple times, once for each input word:

```
$ while read w; do sed -i "s/$w//ig" file2 ; done < file1
$ cat file2
Both the  and  are monarchs. Will the  live? , it is!
```

That can be very slow for large files though (and also matches substrings). You could do it in a single pass with Perl:

```
perl -lpe 'BEGIN{open(A,"file1"); chomp(@k = <A>)} 
                 for $w (@k){s/\b\Q$w\E\b//ig}' file2
```

The `\b` make sure we only match on word boundaries, `\Q\E` make sure `$w` is taken literally. This will stop the script from matching `hiking` but it will still match `high-king`. To avoid that, you need to explicitly list the characters that define a word:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -Mutf8 -lpe '
  BEGIN{open(A,"file1"); chomp(@k = <A>)} 
  for $w (@k){s/(^|[ ,.—_;-])\Q$w\E([ ,.—_;-]|$)/$1$2/ig}' file2
```

That `—` non-ASCII character above needs to be entered in UTF-8 encoding, as we're telling `perl` the code is written in UTF-8 with `-Mutf8`. We're using `-Mopen=locale` for the content of the files and stdout to be decoded/encoded in the locale's character set.

Answer (score 1):

save this script to file `d`: ([DOWNLOAD FROM GITHUB GIST](https://gist.github.com/babyy/1926d9e6813f0ac82875f74c3f1c1330))

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST=${1:?"LIST word"}
FILE=${2:?"FILE name not set"}

L=$( sed -e ':a;N;$!ba;s_\n_\x00_g' ${LIST}|sed -e 's_\x00_ \\|_g' -e's_\(\\|\)*$__g')
P='s_\('$L'\)__ig'
O="sed -e '$P'  ${FILE}"

eval "${O}"
```

then run it:

```
bash ./d LIST FILE
```

if you want save file you can run this command:

```
bash ./d LIST FILE  | tee NewFILE
```

OR

```
bash ./d LIST FILE > NewFile
```

---

i read LIST WORD and change it to regex foramt, for example i change your `queen` and `king` and `test` to this format:

```
queen\|king\|test
```

then create `sed` command with this parameter:

```
sed -e 's_\(queen\|king\|test\) *__ig' FILE
```

with this bash script we read once `LISTWORD` and once `FILE` for replace