# read variable from a file and pass it to sed

Tags: sed

I have two files: `unknown.csv` contains

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

and another file `01.txt` as

```
;lksdjflk aaa lkdsfjdlk
aaa|xxlkjasd|
    |sadkl;k|lsa;dkl
```

when I define a variable as `j=aaa` and try

```
sed "s/${j}//g" 01.txt
```

it will find occurrences of `aaa` and remove it. But if I try to read the `j`  from the `unknown.csv` as

```
j=$(sed '1q;d' unknown.csv)
```

and try

```
sed "s/${j}//g" 01.txt
```

nothing happens. `echo $j` for both cases show same result of `aaa`.

The goal is to read a variable from the `unknow.csv` file and use it to replace it in `01.txt` file.

Thanks

Comment: You should probably have a look at [How to delete all occurrences of a list of words from a text file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/322310/135943)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you create the file unknown.csv on Windows? If so, it probably contains carriage return characters.

Try

```
(set -x; echo "$j" )
```

to show the value of `$j`.

If you want only line 1 and no '\r' at the end, use

```
sed -nr '1s/\r?$//p' unknown.csv
```

Comment: I created it in ubuntu but there is `\r` carriage character in `j` and it showed up when I used `set -x`.  I can remove it using `j=$(sed -e '1q;d' unknown.csv|sed 's/\r//g')`. Is there a better way for that? Thanks

Comment: `1q;d` nonsense aside, it's worth mentioning that working with unknown input requires pre-processing LHS (in this case`$j`) so as to escape any reserved characters.

Comment: @don_crissti - :)

Comment: @mikeserv - hey Mike, good to see you around again !